# How do I duplicate node with connections

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes

I got a node with multiple connections. How can I duplicate it so I wouldn't need to reconnect them all over again? Maybe there is a way to copy connections from one node to another?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> instead of <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate nodes, the duplicate keeps the (input) connections.

Comment: Damn. That's right. Thank you. No such option in the menus, so it didn't occur to me to check the shortcuts.